# Error using TensorFlow 2.0 on Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Google Colab. The link for the project is here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K8aaNq5ZTXQM1zzhaWICuuY5nA06Qn7z?usp=sharing

The error:
[image]

I am learning from a course I found online on https://www.udemy.com/. I do not not know much about tensorflow and I don't know why I am getting this error. You may take a look inside the project and help me find out what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might not be directly a solution to your issue but seems worth noting. When I tried your notebook I had an issue importing 'export_saved_model'.

The solution to that seems to be here on this github repo:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8450

Also, maybe worth noting is that you dont need to install tensorflow into colab as per this tutorial:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb

Hope this helps. Good luck on your course.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I hope I find this helpful

Answer (score 4):

Google Colab specifies

> We recommend against using pip install to specify a particular TensorFlow version for both GPU and TPU backends.

You can read it [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb#scrollTo=-XbfkU7BeziQ)
So I would suggest you directly import dependencies for the project.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
```

```
tf.__version__
```

gives output

> 2.3.0